# SqlAlchemy: engines and connections management

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Both of these work:

```
sel = select([self.tbl])
rec = self.engine.execute(sel)
```

and

```
sel = select([self.tbl])
conn = self.engine.connect()
rec = conn.execute(sel)
```

What is the underlying difference?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html):

- About `connect()`

> The engine can be used directly to issue SQL to the database. The most generic way is first procure a connection resource, which you get via the Engine.connect() method:

```
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select username from users")
for row in result:
    print("username:", row['username'])
connection.close()
```

> The connection is an instance of Connection, which is a proxy object
>   for an actual DBAPI connection. The DBAPI connection is retrieved from
>   the connection pool at the point at which Connection is created.

- About `execute()`

> The above procedure can be performed in a shorthand way by using the execute() method of Engine itself:

```
result = engine.execute("select username from users") for row in result:
    print("username:", row['username'])
```

> Where above, the execute() method acquires a new Connection on its
>   own, executes the statement
>   with that object, and returns the ResultProxy. In this case, the
>   ResultProxy contains a special flag known as close_with_result, which
>   indicates that when its underlying DBAPI cursor is closed, the
>   Connection object itself is also closed, which again returns the DBAPI
>   connection to the connection pool, releasing transactional resources.